# python mingus play xylophone notes

Tags: python, fluidsynth

Am looking to emmulate xylophone notes in python , so I came across mingus library I have successfully emulated piano notes,

```
NOTES = [62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68]
```

and this is how I played them.

```
fluidsynth.init('/usr/share/sounds/sf2/FluidR3_GM.sf2',"alsa")

fluidsynth.play_Note(NOTES[cell],0,100)
```

These are the notes am using for Piano, they doesn't sounds appropriate to me, but what am looking for is to play xylophone notes using the same, so Do mingus has notes to play for xylophones or is there any better alternative to this?

Thanks!!